# Cassandra : Multiple tables vs materialized view

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

Creating materialized view seems to be an easy option compare to multiple tables..but is it a good option?

Since materialized views are nothing but another table in the back drop.

What exactly happens when we create a materialized view over a table and the partition key is changed to clustering key?

I just think creating another table rather than a materilized view is better for long term perspective when the data increase rate is high.

Answer (score 0):

Mvs really helps avoiding overhead of managing multiple tables at client side.  However it has some functional limitations.
[This](https://opencredo.com/everything-need-know-cassandra-materialized-views/) is good blog written on MV.

Also You can see a warning while using MV:

> MVs are experimental and are not recommended for production use.

Personally, I would prefer managing my own table, instead of working with this risk.